# Solapacion de eventos

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo el formulario base de mi aplicacion en c#, y edite un panel para que tome la propiedad de mover el formulario, ya que queria personalizar el mismo. Este es el codigo en cuestión que genere el conflicto entre los eventos:

```
        [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "ReleaseCapture")]
    private extern static void ReleaseCapture();
    [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
    private extern static void SendMessage(IntPtr hand, int wasg, int wparam, int iparam);

    private void pnlBarraDeArrastre_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(Handle, 0x112, 0xf012, 0);
    }
```

Mi duda es: Como puedo ejecutar el evento `doble click` sobre el mismo panel para que se expanda o reduzca, sin que este evento de arrastrar me solape ese evento y no lo ejecute (ya que esta constantemente ocupado con el evento `MouseDown` para mover todo el formulario)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Serias tan amable de hacer un [mcve] para que se pueda probar el problema y buscar una solución?

Comment: esta ocupado porque pones un breakpoint en el mousedown (con lo cual siempre se detiene alli) o si defines ambos en realizar el double click se ejecuta ?

Comment: Perdon la tardanza, estaba en la universidad, basicamente, que el mismo panel, sea capaz de ejecutar el codigo de arriba para que se mueva el control al mantener el click, y que al hacer doble click, este se maximize o tome el tamaño normal del formulario (el problema es que el evento de mantener y arrastrar, bloquea el evento de doble click para hacer lo ultimo que puse)

Comment: Adjunte una foto para ver si se entiende mejor, el evento doble click esta asignado a este evento click ya que hacen lo mismo, para no repetir codigo.